# Xamarin Studio and Mono debug issue with WebPageHttpModule

Tags: mono, monodevelop, servicestack, xamarin-studio

There's a lot to like about the new Xamarin Studio however every time I run my web project I run into the System.Security.SecurityException - no access to the given key.

If I continue execution and refresh the page in Safari the site works. It's only the first time the site loads.

It stops here in the Disassembler:

```
0000001d   call Void System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler:RegisterExtension (String)
00000022   ldc.i4.0 
00000023   call Void System.Web.UI.PageParser:set_EnableLongStringsAsResources (Boolean)
>00000028   ldtoken System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule
0000002d   call Type System.Type:GetTypeFromHandle (RuntimeTypeHandle)
00000032   call Void  Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility:RegisterModule (Type)
00000037   newobj Void System.Web.WebPages.Scope.AspNetRequestScopeStorageProvider:.ctor ()
0000003c   call Void System.Web.WebPages.Scope.ScopeStorage:set_CurrentProvider (IScopeStorageProvider)
00000041   ret
```

It appears to be a race condition. Is it launching the website before it's done all compiling?

To test that I added a Before Execute task of `sleep '8s'` and it doesn't happen straight away but the next time a link is selected. Basically the first time the site is loaded.

I can compile the code and run it on Ubuntu ok. Any ideas?

Some other environment data:

- OS-X Mountain Lion
- .Net 4.0
- Project uses ServiceStack.Net
- MVC 3.0

Comment: this needs a proper fix of the race condition, but not with a sleep; you should open a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ first thing

Answer (score 1):

If others find the same problem, just letting you know the problem has gone away after I did the following (for other reasons)

1. Removed compiled binaries from source control (GitHub) and added a .gitignore file.
2. Opened the solution in VS 2012 - first had to comment out the "Imports ...web.targets" from the website .csproj as these weren't on my Windows machine and prevented the project from loading.
3. Opened the solution back in Xamarin Studio and removed the references VS 2012 automatically added, like .Web.Helpers and .Web.Entity and other references it injected into the web.config.

Xamarin Studio is now slower to start the web site with the debugger as it loads assemblies, each of these takes a second - 
`Loaded assembly: data-0x1d9ac00 [External]` etc But no error :)

So probably it was Git doing something to the binary files in a sub project or a bad DLL reference I happened to remove correctly this time around.